# How to print to pdf using php with a canvas element

Tags: php, jquery, pdf, canvas, pdf-generation

I'm trying to make an on-the-fly PDF generator using PHP, but I'm having one problem so far in that the pages I am trying to generate as a PDF have a bar graph generated by flot using a canvas.

Does anyone have experience with this or know how to get canvas to print to pdf?

I'm also open to the idea of simply having my client load a page that has each graph of the report broken by (print) page using CSS to style page breaks and use the built in Print to PDF printer.

Comment: Which PDF printer do you tested? I had some very good experiences with TCPDF.

Comment: So far I have been able to print an entire webpage using whatever default pdf printer was installed on a windows xp box. I will take a look at what you suggested and test it out tonight. 

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
//Here is the way to generate html into canvas into PDF

1 add can js files
jquery.js
JS/html2canvas.js
JS/jquery.plugin.html2canvas.js

2.get the html content to convert into canvas
        $('.hideDivs').hide(); 
        $('.formdrop').hide();
        $('.block').html2canvas({
            onrendered: function (canvas) {
                 //Set hidden field's value to image data (base-64 string)
                $('#img_val').val(canvas.toDataURL("image/jpg"));
                 $('#img_val3').val($('.block').html()); //html of div
                //Submit the form manualy

            }
        });

3. PHP back end with TC PDF
if(isset($_REQUEST['img_val'])):
        //Get the base-64 string from data
        $filteredData=substr($_POST['img_val'], strpos($_POST['img_val'], ",")+1);
        //Decode the string
        $unencodedData=base64_decode($filteredData);
        //Save the image
        $imgfile=FCPATH.'images/submsnimage_'.$this->session->userdata('admin_id').'.jpg';
        $imagegerated=file_put_contents($imgfile, $unencodedData);
        chmod($imgfile, 0777);
        $pdfImageFile=site_url()."images/submsnimage_".$this->session->userdata('admin_id').'.jpg';
endif;

4 PDF generation
        ini_set('max_execution_time',300);
        require_once (FCPATH.'tcpdf/config/lang/eng.php');
        require_once (FCPATH.'tcpdf/tcpdf.php');
        $exa = new TCPDF ();
        $exa->SetCreator ( PDF_CREATOR );
        $exa->SetAuthor ( 'Clay County Admin' );
        $exa->SetTitle ( 'Clay County Form' );
        $exa->SetSubject ( 'Example of TCPDF' );
        $exa->SetKeywords ( 'TCPDF, PDF, PHP' );
        $exa->SetFont ( 'times', '', 18 ); 
        $exa->AddPage ();
        $exa->Image ($pdfImageFile, 15, 10, 430,630); 
        $exa->AddPage ();
        $exa->Image ($pdfImageFile2, 15, 10, 430,630); 
        $exa->AddPage ();
        $exa->Image ($pdfImageFile3, 15, 10, 430,630); 

        $exa->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);
        $exa->setJPEGQuality (100);
        $root=site_url();
        $exa->setImageScale(1.53);

        $txt ="";
        $exa->WriteHTML ($txt, true, false, true, false, '');
        $exa->Output (FCPATH.'uploads/pdf/clayCommunityBullyReport.pdf', 'F' ); // downloads the pdf
```

Answer (score -3):

I've never used `<canvas>` to try and create/print a pdf.  I would recommend **NOT** using `<canvas>` because it's not supported in all browsers. However There is a function in canvas called: `toDataURL()` that will convert what the canvas is showing to an image which you can then use to save/print however it would be in an image format and not a pdf.

I would recommend using a php library to create a pdf and then display that to the user.  I personally have used FPDF but here is a list of a few:

http://www.fpdf.org/

http://www.tcpdf.org/

http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdf.php